# powershell - how to set a property

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm working with an AD domain where i want to change pssword policy remotely via PowerShell.

I'm here:

```
$domain1 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://test.com")

$domain |get-member
...
masteredBy                       Property   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection masteredBy {get;set;}                       
maxPwdAge                        Property   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection maxPwdAge {get;set;}                        
minPwdAge                        Property   System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection minPwdAge {get;set;}                        
.....
```

--> At this point I see that there is `{get;set;}` in definition of these properties.

The question is: Does it means that you can set `maxPwdAge` in a way like:

`$domain |set-property -name maxPwdAge -value XX`

Please bear in mind that I can't use any cmdlet from active directory module because the remote domain doesn't have the `Active Directory Web Services` running.

This question is to understand the meaning of {get;set;} for properties and to find a PS way to set these values ;-)

Comment: I will delete this if i am wrong but is the Password Policy not configured in Group Policy?

Comment: Usually in PowerShell, you use the get method by calling the property like this: $object.propertyname. In the same way, if the object supports it you should be able to use set like this: $object.propertyname = 'new value'

Answer (score 0):

In this case, those are read-only properties. You would need to edit the Group Policy or call legacy Net* APIs to programmatically change this.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!!! ... in the easiest way :D

after defining $domain with:

```
$domain = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://test.com")
```

i can READ:

```
$domain.maxPwdAge
```

I can SET:

```
$domain.maxPwdAge = 10
$domain.setinfo()
```

I only missed 'setinfo()' method.....after that it finally works!